# Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState': while reading csv file using spark session

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm trying to read a csv file using sparksession and i was getting the below error.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
```

Below is the code i was using to read csv file using sparkSession.

```
ss.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").schema(fileSchema).load("data_sample.csv")
```

I have created the spark session as below:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .set("hive.exec.orc.split.strategy", "ETL")
  .set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
  .set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")

val ss = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().config(conf).appName(applicationName).getOrCreate()
```

My Pom file has below dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <spark.version>2.1.2</spark.version>
</properties>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-xml_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried adding ("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "./spark-warehouse") config while creating the spark session but still I'm getting the same error. I'm using maven to build the project and running the application in IntelliJ.

Is there any config/pom dependency I missed?

Comment: How are you running this application using a spark-submit?

Comment: @Bhanu I'm running this as an application from IntelliJ..

Comment: It can be a reason why you are getting it. You should have Hive installed. I would prefer to pack it as a jar and use spark-submit. In case if you wanted to interactive development suggest to use a spark-shell. Make sure you have hive-site.xml in your spark conf.